# Doctrine mapping many linked tables

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, mapping

I'm working with legacy project in PHP and few of tables in database looks like this:

Table Product:

```
+----+-------------+----------------+
|id  | id_category | id_destination |
+----+-------------+----------------+
|1   | 3           | 1              |
|2   | 2           | 1              |
+----+-------------+----------------+
```

Table Category:

```
+-------------+----------------+
| id          | category_name  |
+-------------+----------------+
| 2           | services       |
| 3           | transport      |
+-------------+----------------+
```

Tables "services" and "transport"

```
+-------------+----------------+   +-------------+----------------+
| id          | name           |   | id          | kilometers     |
+-------------+----------------+   +-------------+----------------+
| 1           | 'foo'          |   | 1           | 156            |
| 2           | 'bar'          |   | 2           | 12             |
+-------------+----------------+   +-------------+----------------+
```

And now where I want check product with ID 1 it will call:

```
$info = SELECT * FROM product WHERE ID = 1;

$table = SELECT category_name FROM category WHERE ID = $info['id_category'];
```

and then:

```
SELECT * FROM $table WHERE id = $info['id_destination'];
```

My question is how can I mapped this in Doctrine.
I'm working on Symfony 2.6

Answer (score -1):

You want to look at adding [Entity classes](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#creating-an-entity-class) in Symfony to handle the data to/from your database; think of these as the database tables themselves.

Then use [Doctrine Association Mapping](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html); this handles lookup tables (like MySQL JOIN's) automatically, allowing you to simply get the `$product`  and automatically have access to `$product->getCategory()` or `$product->getServices()`.

There is an article on this on the Symfony website too which acts as a good introduction:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#relationship-mapping-metadata

Should be enough to get you started.

*On a side note, think of [upgrading Symfony](http://symfony.com/roadmap) to v3 or, at least, v2.8, for long term support before you get too deep.*

Comment: I know how mapping entities in symfony but i dont know how to mapp that special association